# get System.err: "java.net.UnknownHostException" while trying to load image

Tags: android, api, ebay-api

I'm making an app that uses the ebay api to list specific items. i got the api to work, it fetches the json which i parse. Every thing works except loading the image. I know the url is correct, you could try it yourself

```
http:\/\/thumbs1.ebaystatic.com\/pict\/390822678504404000000001_6.jpg
```

i tried various different image loader methods but they all give the same error:
System.err: java.net.UnknownHostException: http://thumbs1.ebaystatic.com/pict/390822678504404000000001_6.jpg

any ideas thanks

Comment: use picasso or glide...for loading the image

Comment: i want to load the image into a int array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso)

```
Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
.load("http://thumbs1.ebaystatic.com/pict/390822678504404000000001_6.jpg")
.fit()
.centerInside()
.into(yourImageView);
```

Add the dependency:

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

Comment: if the answer is helpful you can mark it as correct...thankx